# C++ prelinker error

Tags: c++

Could you please tell me what to do with the following 2 errors I see during linkage ?

Thanx in advance.

```
C++ prelinker: error: std::basic_ostream<T1, T2> &std::basic_ostream<T1, T2>::flush() [with T1=char, T2=std::char_traits<char>] assigned to work\KernelAppComponent_kernel.o and work\KernelAppComponent_kernel.o

C++ prelinker: error: bad instantiation request file -- instantiation assigned to more than one file

ccintppc: Error: C++ prelink operation failed.
Error: build failed
```

The compiler is GreenHills' Multi Compiler for PowerPC architecture and Integrity OS.

Well, after cleaning and rebuilding components within the project, those prelinker errors are somehow removed ( really dont know what happens ) but the following unresolved symbol errors are introduced.  It is just a hello world program. Somebody can tell me what is wrong ?

```
Cleaning KernelAppComponent.mod
Building KernelAppComponent.mod
Compiling MainKernelAppComponent.cpp because MainKernelAppComponent.o does not exist
Compiling KernelApp.cpp because KernelApp.o does not exist
Linking KernelAppComponent because it does not exist
Compiling KernelAppComponent_kernel.cc because KernelAppComponent_kernel.o does not exist
Compiling global_table.c because global_table.o does not exist
Linking KernelAppComponent_kernel because it does not exist
C++ prelinker: std::basic_ostream<T1, T2> &std::basic_ostream<T1, T2>::put(T1) [with T1=char, T2=std::char_traits<char>] assigned to file work\KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
C++ prelinker: std::basic_ostream<T1, T2> &std::basic_ostream<T1, T2>::flush() [with T1=char, T2=std::char_traits<char>] assigned to file work\KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
Compiling KernelAppComponent_kernel.cc because reg.h has changed
Compiling global_table.c because reg.h has changed
Linking KernelAppComponent_kernel because KernelAppComponent_kernel.o has changed

[elxr] (error) unresolved symbols: 20
 _main         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 clear__Q2_3std8ios_baseFQ3_3std14_Iosb__tm__2_i8_Iostateb         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __ghsLockCpp         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 _Id_cnt__Q3_3std6locale2id         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __ghsUnlockCpp         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __vtbl__Q2_3std9type_info         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 _Getctyptab         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 _Psave__Q2_3std41_Facetptr__tm__24_Q2_3std14ctype__tm__2_c         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 id__Q2_3std17ctype__tm__2_c__S         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 _Getfacet__Q2_3std6localeCFUi         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __nw__FUi         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __ct__Q2_3std8_LocinfoFPCc         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __dt__Q2_3std8_LocinfoFv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 _Register__Q3_3std6locale5facetFv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 cout__3std         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __dl__FPv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __dla__FPv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __ct__Q3_3std8ios_base4InitFv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __record_needed_destruction         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o
 __dt__Q3_3std8ios_base4InitFv         from KernelAppComponent_kernel.o

[elxr] (error) errors during processing
Error: build failed
Build failed (Tue Jul 01 10:48:23 2008)
```

Comment: Which compiler? There aren't many google hits for ccintppc. It sounds like your prelinker expects template code to be generated in exactly one object passed in, though, and somehow you've got code for a character stream flush() generated in two different objects.

Comment: Green Hills is an EDG-based compiler. EDG is of course famous for its `export` capability and general template savvyness.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this kind of error numerous times using the Green Hills Multi compiler.  As [Rup's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234183/c-prelinker-error#comment5890626_5234183) states, this is due to template code being instantiated for the same concrete class in 2 (or more) object files, causing an error at linking time.  I don't think I've ever seen this occur when doing a clean build, so this seems to only happens when a project is re-linked after having some subset of the files recompiled.
This makes some sense: during the original full build, the template instantiation T was arbitrarily associated with the object file Foo.o.  Then later, Bar.c was modified and when recompiled T became associated with Bar.o too.  And then you get a linking error.

I'd figured out the above a long time ago, but had never figured out how to quickly resolve it.  (I often had to resort to reverting to a clean build.)  But now after having read [AProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234622/2124447), I'm happy to report that deleting the corresponding .ii files does resolve the issue.

In general, if you receive a linking error such as

`C++ prelinker: error: std::basic_ostream<T1, T2> &std::basic_ostream<T1, T2>::flush() [with T1=char, T2=std::char_traits<char>] assigned to path\to\Foo.o and another\path\to\Bar.o`

then to resolve the error, delete the corresponding .ii files at `path\to\Foo.ii` and 
`another\path\to\Bar.ii`, respectively, and try linking again.  Note that you may still get another set of conflicts, so you may need to repeat the cycle a few times before linking finally completes.

(Please note that in the [OP's original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5234183), the two paths were the same, so as [Rob Kennedy stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5234546/2124447), this particular case was probably due to a project file error such as having the same source file twice in the list of compilation targets or having the same object file twice in the list of linking targets.)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the error mentions the same file name twice. Perhaps you've inadvertently mentioned it twice on your linker's command line.

Answer (score 1):

`bad instantiation request file` I'd try to remove that file which is way to reduce the number of iterations needed when using the *iterated instantiation mechanism*, but if it is corrupted, correct compilation can be prevented.

If I'm right in guessing that this compiler is based on the EDG front end, it is probably a file named "xxx.ii".

Answer (score 1):

The code segment under question belongs to a monolith project, which means a kernel image accompanying a virtual-address-space image under one roof ( this is GreenHills' MULTI IDE and Integrity OS terminology )

The monolith project was automatically generated via MULTI IDE.

Since I could not resolve the problem, I created a new Monolith project from scratch and noticed that there is a setting where the language is selected as either C or C++.

Selecting C++ is, I guess, is the main issue here, which seems to be not handled appropriately by MULTI IDE.

So, I dont encounter those problems any more.